# How to LOLA DEM 16bit signed TIFF to QGIS Greyscale (BumpMap) image?

Tags: qgis, convert, altitude

I have a moon 16bit signed TIFF downloaded to my computer from http://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/details/Moon/LMMP/LOLA-derived/Lunar_LRO_LOLA_ClrShade_Global_128ppd_v04/cub

- **A pointer please in the right direction to convert the image to greyscale with QGIS but keep the greyscale in keeping with the altitudes.**
- **That is to say running smoothly through the greyscale running white to black smoothly. Getting gradually darker as the altitude decreases?**

In the downloaded TIFF...

WHITE is highest and then RED to YELLOW and on to GREENS, BLUES and VIOLETS.
Using Photoshop and choosing make Greyscale results in mixing the altitudes up.

Original picture source is huge.

I have downloaded 550 pixels per meter giving a file size of 1.43 GB.

Should be way more than i need to make a good bump map from the correctly converted greyscale.

[image]

Comment: Picture comes from http://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/details/Moon/LMMP/LOLA-derived/Lunar_LRO_LOLA_ClrShade_Global_128ppd_v04/cub

Comment: @Luke it can be downloaded as JPEG2000 also. Have learned that QGIS can be downloaded for the Macintosh and has more opportunity to help me with my goal than Photoshop. QGIS installed, file opened and displaying correctly the full colour image. But where to start with QGIS. i am familiar with Photoshop but instantly lost in QGIS. I just need a pointer in the right direction. something to try perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  That is a derived "hillshade" product and does not contain any elevation values.  From the link you provided:

> Pixels do not contain any of the original explicit elevation information.

You need to download the raw elevation values.

Comment: would this do the job? http://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/details/Moon/LRO/LOLA/Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014/cub

Comment: Last link is better. Results come forward from this. Thank you for your knowledge. I see this original picture is NOT the right image for what i want to achieve. This question is answered.